# How to add new item in specific index?

Tags: collections, kotlin

I new in kotlin , i want to update an item in lists.
I use this code:

```
var index: Int
    for (record in recordList)
        if (record.id == updatedHeader?.id) {
            index = recordList.indexOf(record)
            recordList.add(index, updatedHeader)
        }
```

but it cant do this, because of `ConcurrentModificationException`

Comment: Is the record with the specified `id` unique in the list? Do I get right that you want to _prepend_ the header before the record with the matching id?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `recordList` is a `MutableList` and `val` (so, you'd like to modify the records in place), you can use `forEachIndexed` to find the records you care about and replace them.

This did not cause a `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
recordList.forEachIndexed { index, record -> 
    if(record.id == updatedHeader?.id) recordList[index] = updatedHeader
}
```

On the other hand, if you redefine `recordList` as a non-mutable list, and a var, you could rewrite the entire list using `map`:

```
recordList = recordList.map { if(it.id == updatedHeader?.id) updatedHeader else it }
```

Of course, you could call `.toMutableList()` on the end of that if you wanted to turn your `List` into a `MutableList`.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a single record with the given `id` in the list, you can find its index and add the header at that index:

```
    val index = recordList.indexOfFirst { it.id == updatedHeader.id }
    if (index >= 0)
        recordList.add(index, updatedHeader)
```

If there are multiple records with the given id and you want to prepend header before each of them, you can use get `listIterator` and use its methods to modify the list during the iteration without getting `ConcurrentModificationException`:

```
    val iterator = recordList.listIterator()
    for (record in iterator) {
        if (record.id == updatedHeader.id) {
            iterator.previous()  // move to the position before the record
            iterator.add(updatedHeader) // prepend header
            iterator.next() // move next, back to the record
        }
    }
```